# The jquery keyup event is not working

Tags: asp.net, jquery, sharepoint-2007

I am working on making a Sharepoint 2007 app look more modern. I am using jQuery actively for that and even though I am no expert, I have learnt enough to know my ways around. Untill I faced this issue today. Here are the bits:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert('doc ready');
    var textBox1 = $("#myTest");
    alert(textBox1);

    textBox1.keyup(function() {
        alert('key UP');
    });

    textBox1.live("keyup", function() {
        alert('keykeykey up live');
    });

});
```

**Server-generated html:**

```
    <input name="ctl00$Spwebpartmanager1$g_1f2d211c_a0c3_490d_8890_028afd098cac$ctl00$myTest" type="password" id="ctl00_Spwebpartmanager1_g_1f2d211c_a0c3_490d_8890_028afd098cac_ctl00_myTest" class="gh" />
```

So the document ready handler fires, the textbox1 variable is not null, but none of the eventhandlers to handle the keyup event ever fire? The mind reels...

Comment: Consider setting ClientIDMode http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx

Comment: @Šime Vidas , i am under 3.5 unfortunately so no go for that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doesn't work because the id attribute is actaully `ctl00_Spwebpartmanager1_g_1f2d211c_a0c3_490d_8890_028afd098cac_ctl00_myTest`

try

[`var textBox1 = $("input[id$='_myTest']");`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

Here were looking for a html input field with has an id attribute that ends with the string `_myTest`

In future for your debugging use

`alert(textBox1.length)`

So that you can whether the jQuery object is empty or not. If the selector doesn't find anything it will return an empty jQuery object which isn't null. You can test for whether the selector found anything by making sure that the [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property is positive.

Comment: Ok thanks I will, but.. the var textBox1 = $("#myTest");  line returns a valid object..

Comment: @Max `$()` will return a jQuery object even if the selector didn't match any elements.

Comment: @Sime - cool, but why? And another thing this same code does work just honky dory if ran under the normal asp.net web application.

Comment: @Max as mentioned what jQuery returns is a jQuery object, not a DOM object. Even if the jQuery object has no DOM object attached to it, it will still return a `non-null` value

Comment: @Max the problem is your sharepoint stuff adding junk to the start of your id.

Comment: It will be a valid jquery object but it won't contain any elements. If you do alert(textBox1.length); my bet is that you will alert 0. Another way would be to target all inputs with class gh "$(".gh").live("keyup", function(){});". But using class selectors without a set id root can be slow in IE as IE doesn't support the base getElementsByClass.

Comment: @Max `$()` always returns a jQuery object. That jQuery object contains zero or more DOM elements. If the selector didn't match and elements, then obviously the jQuery object will contain none.

Comment: @Raynos - should not selector say: 
var textBox1 = $("input[id$='myTest']");

instead of the _myTest?

Comment: @Max doesn't matter. As you can see the auto generated junk id ends with "_myTest" I can imagine it's common practice to prepend it with (junk + "_"). You can test for either. Of course if you use it in normal code that doesn't have auto generated id's then yes using "_myTest" would fail.

Comment: @Raynos - ok back to reading the theory...should have known as this seems to be the basics. Thanks!